# Laravel Controller Refactor (validation and request manipluation)

Tags: laravel, controller, refactoring

Where should you store the request validation when the request first needs to be manipulated before being passed for validation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code much cleaner and readable I've used laravel repositories package
at https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository